# Randomly select a value from a column for each unique value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been working on a task that seems pretty straightforward. However, I've spent this entire day without progressing and I believe it's now time to ask this community for help. I have the following table with simply 2 columns:

| Person | key numbers |
| --- | --- |
| PersonA | 11111 |
| PersonA | 22222 |
| PersonA | 33333 |
| PersonB | 44444 |
| PersonB | 55555 |

I need to randomly select a key number associated with a person and display it in a new table. I need to display all persons alongside a random key number. The number of keys associated with a person ranges from 2-5. An example of the output table is displayed below:

| Person | key numbers |
| --- | --- |
| PersonA | 22222 |
| PersonB | 44444 |

Any ideas on how to approach this task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a "Top 1 in each group" but order the data by `NEWID()`? (It won't be particularly performant mind, but such tasks rarely are.)

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` then take rows where row-number =1

Comment: Why do you need to do this at all? Often when these questions are asked here on SO (i.e. "get me random data"), digging into the business requirements exposes a shaky foundation.

Comment: Does it actually need to be random or just arbitrary?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :

`SELECT DISTINCT Person ,FIRST_VALUE([key numbers]) OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY NEWID()) FROM TABLE`